# NextJs multiple POST's with the same body not saving to mongoDB when send in Browser, but working in Postman

Tags: post, next.js, postman, next.js13

I am learning to use NextJS v13 and i got stuck.
I created app that has searchbar where user can insert any name and gets response with propabylty of what country that name is from and what gender propably that name is. Then that search with its results is saved to mongodb to create history of all searches made by users.
Preview of that app can be found at:
[name inspector preview](https://name-inspector.vercel.app/)

And the code can be found on github: [name inspector - github](https://github.com/Kinetic639/name-inspector)

I have a problem i got stuck on and can't figur out how to fix:
When i type different name everytime everything works perfect and every search with results is saved to the db.
But when i search for the same name multiple times within short span everything seems fine and everywhere i get status 200 but data is saved not immediately but a with delay.
This only happens in the browser. When using postman i can send post request with results for the same name over and over again and everytime it works fine saving it.

Everything also works if i open multiple tabs and search for the same name in each of them - all results will get saved to the db.

So seems like in nextjs i have to wait some time between sending post to the same endpoint with the same body? Is there a way to fix it?